# How can I add a Text Area widget that the users can paste clickable URL's into?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm creating an App using Google AppMaker, and would like the end user to be able to insert a clickable URL link into a 'Comments' column

Comment: I might suggest using the text editor widget for the entry portion and then use the HTML widget to present it in like a table. However if you are just needing to paste the URL you can also use a text box and then still use a HTML widget to present it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

It might look something like this:

```
var urlText=CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('url')
  .setMultiline(true)
  .setTitle('URL');
  section.addWidget(urlText);
```